# Why is Heroku push failing from Cloud9?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku

I signed in to Heroku through my Rails app but when I go to push, I get this error:

```
    -----> Ruby app detected
    -----> Compiling Ruby/Rails
   sh: 1: Gemfile: not found
   !
   !     There was an error parsing your Gemfile, we cannot continue
   !     
   !     [!] There was an error parsing `Gemfile`: syntax error, unexpected
          keyword_end, expecting end-of-input. Bundler cannot continue.
   !     
   !     #  from /tmp/build_68de181abe890ef0e6c625b9af15fb4a/Gemfile:63
   !     #  -------------------------------------------
   !     #    end
   !     >  end
   !     #
   !     #  -------------------------------------------
   !
   !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app.
   !     Push failed
```

I can't find this error in my gemfile:

```
  source 'https://rubygems.org'


  gem 'rails', '4.2.5'
 gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
 gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
 gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
 gem 'jquery-rails'
 gem 'turbolinks'
 gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
 gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc
 gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.3', '>= 3.3.6'
 gem 'font-awesome-sass', '~> 4.5'
 gem 'bootstrap-sass-extras', '~> 0.0.2'
 gem 'devise', '~> 3.5', '>= 3.5.6'
 gem 'simple_form', '~> 3.2', '>= 3.2.1'
 gem 'will_paginate', '~> 3.1'
 gem 'will_paginate-bootstrap', '~> 1.0', '>= 1.0.1'


 group :development, :test do
  gem 'byebug'
 end

 group :development do
  gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'sqlite3'
 end

 group :production do
  gem 'rails_12factor', '~> 0.0.3'
  gem 'pg', '~> 0.18.4'
 end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message states that there's an extra `end` at line 63. If you have removed it from your Gemfile, make sure to commit your changes then try to push again.